# How do I compare a value of a class to a Interface that includes that class?

Tags: java

This would be a method in Video where the IMedia interface could be a Video, Article, or Recording. Only a Video and Article use the field "name".

```
// is the name of this Video the same 
// as that of the given IMedia?

public boolean sameCorporation(IMedia that) {
  return (this.name == that.name);
}
```

I know that "this.name == that.name" does not work as it seems the interface doesnt know how to resolve.

interface only contains method bodies

```
//to represent different types of news media
interface IMedia {

  // compute the length of this IMedia
  int length();

  // formats the title, corporation, and episode number of IMedia
  String format();

  // is the corporation of this media the same 
  // as the corporation of the given media?
  boolean sameCorporation(IMedia that);
}
```

Comment: We don't have enough information. What does the `IMedia` interface contain?

Comment: The interface is a contract. So, unless there's a `getName` or some method specified in the interface, you cannot expect to be able to access the name field from `IMedia that`. The interface doesn't know about the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IMedia` probably does not have a `name` field, the subclasses do. So you would have to cast, but that is a bad design.

You can have a new interface

```
public interface Nameable {
    public String getName();
}
```

And your other one extends that

```
public interface IMedia extends Nameable {
    // other stuff
}
```

You have some class with a name field

```
public class Video implements IMedia {
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    // Video things
}
```

Some class with no name that still implements IMedia, just return null for the `getName()`.

And your comparison method should be fine

```
public boolean sameCorporation(IMedia that) {
  // compare strings correctly, avoid nullpointer
  return that != null && Objects.equals(this.name, that.getName()); 
}
```

---

Probably best use an abstract class at this point.

```
public interface IMedia extends Nameable {
    // other stuff
    boolean sameCorporation(IMedia that);
}

public abstract class AbstractMedia implements IMedia {

    public abstract String getName();

    public boolean sameCorporation(IMedia that) {
        return that != null && Objects.equals(this.getName(), that.getName()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Woah! I didn't know about the `Objects.equals` method. Damn! So much to learn.

Comment: Yup. Java7+ I was looking for a `static String.compare(String, String)` method, but seems there is none

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use interface composition instead of inheritance here if not all media are nameable (`public class Video implements IMedia, Nameable`)?

Comment: @MickMnemonic Then `IMedia.getName()` does not exist

Comment: Right. Just had a look at OP's requirements and it seems that only a single interface is what is asked. Perhaps a default method returning an empty string in `Nameable`, then?

Comment: I try to stick to pre-Java8 for some unknown reason unless I am forced into lambdas and streams.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `getName()` method in your interface `IMedia`.

```
interface IMedia {
  String getName();
  int length();
  String format();
  boolean sameCorporation(IMedia that);
}
```

Then, you could compare by calling this new method.

```
public boolean sameCorporation(IMedia that) {
  return this.getName() == that.getName();
}
```

Given that only `Video` and `Article` have a name. You could return null in `Recording.getName()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces do not have properties. They only provide method declarations which are implemented in classes. So in your case the `IMedia` interface should declare a method `getName` or something like that.

```
public interface IMedia {
    String getName();
    //...
    //Your other methods
}
```

You said only Articles and Videos have names. So you could define another interace which extends `IMedia`.

```
public interface INamedMedia extends IMedia {
    String getName();
}
```

Your `Video` and `Article` classes could then implement `INamedMedia`.

The second thing I see here. `name` is probably a String. You never should compare Strings with `==`. Use the `equals` method instead.

```
this.getName().equals(that.getName())
```